# Не могу завести jCarousel

Tags: javascript, jcarousel

Воспользовался статьей: `http://zencoder.ru/slider-jcarousel/`
Изучил основы, применил к своему проекту... но он не работает!
Даже скопировал все документы из статьи - эффект тот же самый, не работает.
Где я косячу?
Вот для примера выложил код из статьи, подгрузил сам скрипт с сайта карусели:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.jcarousel').jcarousel({
      // Базовые настройки скрипта пишутся здесь
  });

  // Инициализация прокрутки слайдера
  $('.jcarousel-prev').jcarouselControl({
      target: '-=1'
  });

  $('.jcarousel-next').jcarouselControl({
      target: '+=1'
  });
});
```

```css
@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3/border-radius";
@import "compass/css3/box-shadow";
@import "compass/typography/links/hover-link";
@import "compass/typography/text/replacement";

$nav_width: 30px;
$nav_height: $nav_width;

.wrap_jcarousel{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  @include border-radius(10px);
  @include box-shadow(rgba(0,0,0,.3) 2px 2px 10px);
  .jcarousel {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    ul{
      width: 20000em;
      position: relative;
      li{
        float: left;
        img{
          vertical-align: top;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /*  PREV NEXT BUTTONS  */
  .jcarousel-prev,
  .jcarousel-next{
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    display: block;
    width: $nav_width;
    height: $nav_height;
    background-color: #778899;
    @include border-radius(50%);
    @include squish-text;
    @include box-shadow(rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0 0 4px inset);
    &:hover{
      background-color: darken(#778899,10%);
    }
    &.inactive{
      cursor: default;
    }
  }
  .jcarousel-prev{
    left: -50px;
  }
  .jcarousel-next{
    right: -50px;
  }

  /*  PAGINATION  */
  .jcarousel-pagination{
    background-color: transparent;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    a{
      text-decoration: none;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
      @include border-radius(50%);
      margin-left: 5px;
      &:first-child{
        margin-left: 0;
      }
      &:hover{
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
      }
      &.active{
        opacity: .7;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap_jcarousel">
  <div class="jcarousel">
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/778899/fff&text=Slide 1" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/778899/fff&text=Slide 2" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/778899/fff&text=Slide 3" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/778899/fff&text=Slide 4" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/778899/fff&text=Slide 5" alt="" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/600x400/778899/fff&text=Slide 6" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--  end jcarousel  -->
  <!--  CONTROLS  -->
  <a class="jcarousel-prev" href="#">Prev</a>
  <a class="jcarousel-next" href="#">Next</a>
</div><!--  end wrap_jcarousel  -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Так всегда... ломаешь голову, ломаешь...
А только выложишь вопрос - тут же решение нашел))
Надо было задать размер контейнеру что перед ul со значением 20000em

```
#news-slide1 {width: 900px;}
```